# Detach Disk from deleted virtual machine

Tags: azure

I had an Virtual Machine running in Azure for a couple of weeks and suddenly it stopped responding.  I shut it down and tried to restart it but that failed saying the VM faulted.  I then deleted the VM which leaves the VHD file intact on my storage account.

I was intending to try recreating a new VM using thie VHD from the first VM however, the OS disk and Data disk are both still marked as being attached to the original VM which no longer exists.

Is there any way to detach these disks so I can use them to create a new VM?

Answer (score 2):

When you delete a Virtual Machine the VHD is still in lease so you would need to break the lease first so you can reuse the VHD.

Please follow the article below to release the lease first and the reuse the VHD:

[Error deleting VHD: There is currently a lease on the blob and no lease ID was specified in the request](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/WAVirtualMachinesforWindows/thread/7381ea0e-0443-4b33-aa12-ba39df003409)

IF you still have problem write back and I will help.